# It seems to me that I found a function that works faster than std:max

Tags: c++, function, optimization

One day I came across a task to determine the maximum among 2 numbers without conditional operators and loops (as well as bit operations). After thinking, I came to this decision:

```
long long mmax(long long a, long long b) {
    return (a+b+(a-b)*((2*(a-b)+1)%2))/2;
}
```

Just for fun I decided to check, which function is faster, so I tested both functions on 3 data sample containing 10^7 pairs of random integers from 1 to 10^17 about 100 times. I was surprised because every call of my function worked faster on at least 0.092 seconds on integers from 1 to 10^5 and at least 0.044 seconds faster on integers from 10^5 to 10^17. On average, my function worked 0.1 seconds faster on integers from 1 to 10^5 and on 0.06 seconds faster on integers from 10^5 to 10^17. So, I am not a specialist in optimization and because of that I am asking if this function really faster than std:max?

Here is my test code:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

long long mmax(long long a, long long b) {
    return (a+b+(a-b)*((2*(a-b)+1)%2))/2;
}

int main(){
    auto started = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    ifstream in("bilt.txt");

    long long a, b;
    while(in >> a >> b) {
        mmax(a,b);
    }

    auto done = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(done-started).count() << endl;

}
```

Comment: I don't think this works correctly for all values `long long` can represent. If you have overflows you have undefined behavior even if it works for you when you try it. And it's not clear how you tested this. The benchmark may be incorrect or biased.

Comment: Trust me, you haven't.  There might be domains where this is faster but in general it will not be.  In general, you **can't** beat `std::swap` as it uses move semantics if possible,

Comment: *"This thing I wrote runs faster than ..."* -- but we have no code, no indication how the application was built, etc.

Comment: Also, running code a 100 times is way too little.  When benchmarking you need to run your code at least a few hundred thousand times to get a true average.

Comment: You're including the cost of I/O in your timing loop, which clobbers any time spent in the code you're trying to time.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I checked on very big long longs, it works correctly

Comment: You are including file I/O in your benchmark which will probably dominate your test. Additionally, since you don't do anything with the function's results it will probably be optimized out meaning you are likely *only* measuring file I/O.

Comment: @Mouvre As I said, it's not because it worked *for you* that it's correct. You have undefined behavior if `a+b` or any other intermediary value exceed the maximum value for a `long long` and it won't necessarily work for everyone every time.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux so what should I do to calculate pure function`s work time?

Comment: @Mouvre You need to check better.  It doesn't work here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7ed57b22764bb61

Comment: @Mouvre Read the values to a container ahead of time and do something with the result that affects the observable behavior. For example, save the results to a preallocated container and save them to a file or something. You will still have problems with sampling and bias. It's very very hard to generalize a benchmark when you don't have a specific use case. Bench marking is usually done with real application code where any bias is likely to be part of the normal use case and isn't problematic.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica You are right, but isn't it still applicable to little less long long values?

Comment: @Mouvre It will only work if the `a + b` is less than `std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() `.  If it isn't, you'll have signed integer overflow and get incorrect results.  see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90d5771c7ba59973 where I use half the max plus 1 and plus 2 respectively.  It still gives a negative result because it overflows.

Comment: @Mouvre I have added a better benchmark in a link in my answer. It uses the google benchmark framework. And now a major flaw that my previous benchmark had is also fixed. Doing benchmarks right is difficult!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your benchmark is not benchmarking `max`. It is completely limited by the time the input operations take. Input operations take many times longer than `std::max` or your `mmax` implementation.

Furthermore, the `mmax` or `std::max` calls will be optimized out by any optimizing compiler, because their results are never used and they don't have any other side effect. See e.g. [here on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6pw2b7). So you are likely not benchmarking them *at all*.

---

Assuming your claims were even true:

Your function has undefined behavior for some arguments, which `std::max` doesn't have, e.g. `a+b` has undefined behavior if it causes an overflow. Comparing the speed is therefore really unfair, since your implementation doesn't even always work.

---

[Here is a quick-bench](http://quick-bench.com/Ou5-7SoHpe1DbW4YWA4YwKhTXkA) with a better (though not rigorously verified) benchmark.

- "std_impl" uses `std::max`
- "naive_impl" uses a simple branch to get the maximum
- "op_impl" is the implementation in the question
- "only_iter" just passes through the first value without any calculation

As you can see in the plot, your implementation is worse than the naive one or `std::max`, both of which are equal in performance.

The naive and standard library implementations do however, contrary to yours, actually work with all possible input values (I restricted the test case values in the vector to a range that works with your implementation.)

---

In a previous version of this benchmark I made a mistake (doing benchmarks right is difficult!) that made it seem as if the naive implementation was much worse than `std::max` and OP's implementation, which turned out to be an artifact of how google benchmark's `DoNotOptimize` works (at least on Clang, maybe this is a bug in google benchmark or maybe I was using it wrong). If someone finds another flaw, let me know please!

---

Benchmark code:

```
#include<random>
#include<cmath>
#include<utility>
#include<algorithm>

const auto N = 10'000;

auto values = []{
  std::vector<std::pair<long long, long long>> v;
  std::default_random_engine rng{std::random_device{}()};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<long long> dist{-100'000'000, 100'000'000};
  for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
    v.emplace_back(dist(rng), dist(rng));
  return v;
}();


void std_impl(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
      for(auto& x : values) {
        auto result = std::max(x.first, x.second);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
      }
  }
}

void naive_impl(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
      for(auto& x : values) {
        auto result = x.first > x.second ? x.first : x.second;
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
      }
  }
}

long long mmax(long long a, long long b) {
    return (a+b+(a-b)*((2*(a-b)+1)%2))/2;
}

void op_impl(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
      for(auto& x : values) {
        auto result = mmax(x.first, x.second);
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
      }
  }
}

void only_iter(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
      for(auto& x : values) {
        auto result = x.first;
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(result);
      }
  }
}

BENCHMARK(std_impl);
BENCHMARK(naive_impl);
BENCHMARK(op_impl);
BENCHMARK(only_iter);
```

Comment: ! Now that's conclusive.

Comment: Okay, that was pretty bad :P

Comment: Google's documentation claims that `DoNotOptimize` only prevents optimization of the result but still optimizes the expression itself. From your results it seems like this is true on GCC (where the previous benchmark did work) but not clang.

Comment: @interjay The code for `DoNotOptimize` has different overloads based on const qualifier: https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/master/include/benchmark/benchmark.h#L307 `std::max` was returning a `const` reference, while the naive implementation returned a non-`const` reference. I assume that was the cause for the difference, one way or another. I don't know how the compilers behave with the compiler barriers exactly. There is also an `#if defined(__clang__)` in there...

Comment: @walnut Oh, very useful result! But I still confused why my function showed better time in all my tests

Comment: ***I still confused why my function showed better time in all my tests*** Your benchmark was flawed. It's easy to get an false result when it comes to optimizations.

Comment: @Mouvre Did you test them in a particular order? If so, try reversing it. Any difference that you see is either because you didn't enable optimizations or because of some effect outside your program. No matter whether you use your implementation or `std::max` in your code, the generated assembly is 100% identical, see https://godbolt.org/z/TzCAfx